# why does MySQL Trigger that uses cursor only fetch one value

Tags: mysql, triggers, cursor

I have created a Trigger after INSERT on the table **AcademicYearTermLevel** which uses a cursor value fetched from another query. I want to use each cursor value in a while loop and insert rows into table **SubjectYearTermLevel**.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_academicyearterm_insert
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_academicyearterm_insert
AFTER INSERT 
ON AcademicYearTerm
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  DECLARE temp INT;
  DECLARE subj_done, form_done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE s_id INT;
  DECLARE curSubject CURSOR FOR SELECT subject_id FROM Subject;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET subj_done = TRUE;

  SET temp = 1;

  OPEN curSubject;
  cur_subject_loop:   LOOP
  FETCH FROM curSubject INTO s_id;

    IF subj_done THEN
    CLOSE curSubject;
    LEAVE cur_subject_loop;
    END IF;

    WHILE temp <= 6 DO
      INSERT INTO SubjectYearTermLevel VALUES (NULL, s_id, NEW.yearTerm_id, temp);
      SET temp = temp + 1;
    END WHILE


  END LOOP cur_subject_loop;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However the problem is that the cursor only seems to fetch one value from the `SELECT` query

Comment: In databases, you will use cursors only as a last resort if and only if all other possibilities fail. Your description sound like it should be doable by a single query joining two resultsets. Could you add a sample result (e.g. the content of table `subject` and the expected result - the new rows - in `tableB`). And also the relation to the inserted row (in `tableA`) - currently you seem to not be using any information about the current row, which is what a trigger is usually about.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, I  `SET temp = 1;` outside the FETCH, and hence after the first cursor value, the while loop never ran.

```sql
  -- SET temp = 1;

  OPEN curSubject;
  cur_subject_loop:   LOOP
  FETCH FROM curSubject INTO s_id;
    SET temp = 1;

    IF subj_done THEN
    CLOSE curSubject;
    LEAVE cur_subject_loop;
    END IF;

    1_to_6_temp: WHILE temp <= 6 DO
      INSERT INTO SubjectYearTermLevel VALUES (NULL, s_id, NEW.yearTerm_id, temp, -1);
      SET temp = temp + 1;
    END WHILE 1_to_6_temp;
  -- CLOSE curSubject;
  END LOOP cur_subject_loop;
```